# th:text doesn't display properly

Tags: java, css, spring

So I'm working on a Petclinic project, and I've been trying to change the title as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7y5B.jpg)

But when I run the application, there's an error in the title as it displays question marks. How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove th:text=" ".  I think it will solve your issue.

## Welcome To Pet Clinic